# load ajax content into colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want to load an ajax response into the colorbox. The colorbox should open on click and show the loading image until the content is fetched and displayed.

**My code:**

```
jQuery(".likeBar").colorbox({initialWidth:'460px', initialHeight:'355px', width:'460px', height:'355px', overlayClose:true, html: function() {
    var eventID = jQuery(this).data("id");
    var sp_response = "";
    var the_data =
    {
        action: 'get_likes',
        eventID: eventID,
        };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, the_data, function(sp_response) {
        return sp_response;
    });
}
});
```

**My problem:**
The fetched content won't be displayed in my colorbox. The AJAX call is successful and the content is fetched, but not displayed.

**My question:**
How to insert content from an ajax call into the colorbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem:

```
jQuery(".likeBar").click(function(){
    var eventID = jQuery(this).data("id");
    var sp_response = "";
    var the_data =
    {
        action: 'get_likes',
        eventID: eventID,
        tb_check_code: tb_check_code
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, the_data).done(function(sp_response) {
        jQuery('#sp_likebox' + eventID).html(sp_response);
     });

    jQuery('#sp_likebox' + eventID).show();
    jQuery(this).colorbox({initialWidth:'460px', initialHeight:'355px', width:'460px', height:'355px', overlayClose:true, inline:true, href: '#sp_likebox' + eventID, title: 'Diesen Benutzern gefällt der Beitrag'});

    jQuery(this).colorbox({
        onCleanup:function(e){
            jQuery('#sp_likebox' + eventID).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2

I've read colorbox docs and found that you can get the content using ajax by providing just the href property and the data property.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

EDIT
Try to make the ajax call async false like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: the_data,
  success: function(sp_response) {
        return sp_response;
    },
  dataType: 'html',
  async: false
});
```

Comment: I want the colorbox to open instantly after the click and not after the ajax call finishes.

Comment: then try the second approach and replace your Jquery.post shorthand functions with the one in my answer. It will load the content because it will by in sync!

Comment: But that will cause the browser to lagg and the user can't do anything else.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm missing something, what else should they do if they have a modal window on top the page? they can still go to other tabs of the browser if that is your concern.

Comment: in my opinion it's just a bad experience if the whole browser laggs. I will post my solution as an answer in a second. Thanks anyone.